# How can I assign expressions to a variable for read line?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a bash `while read line` block reading from a text file specified by `$filename`:

```
IFS=''
while read -r line
do
    ...
done < $filename
```

Instead of reading the whole file each time, I would like to supply different inputs in the redirect depending on the arguments supplied to the script.

- Whole file: `done < "$filename"`
- start at line x: `done < <(tail -n +"$x" "$filename")`
- line x to line y: `done < <(tail -n +"$x" "$filename" | head -n "$y")`
- start to line y: `done < <(head -n "$y" "$filename")`

How can I assign these inputs to a variable ahead of time to be read by the while loop?

---

My input file is ~4GB with some 58M lines (all with different lengths), and may grow or shrink from time to time.  Reading https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file it appears that `tail | head` is the fastest method to read from the middle of a file, so given the file size, I'm deliberately avoiding `awk` and `sed` for the most part.

Comment: If performance is truly a goal -- how many lines do you typically expect to skip? Does your file format contain line numbers, timestamps, or other content that lets you start reading from a byte offset and then figure out a logical offset? Is there a reason you need to start from line offsets, and not byte offsets, at all?

Comment: the file has none of those niceties, though i can work on it somewhat out of order.  eventually i want to get to a point where the file is split into multiple parts, each manipulated by a separate child processes.

Comment: How common are reads, as opposed to writes? If you only get a new batch of files once a day, but search through them frequently, building a file that maps line numbers to byte offsets will pay off -- that way you could use something like [bsearch](https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/blob/master/bsearch/bsearch) to look up the appropriate offsets in O(log n) time, then use `dd` to extract only the desired segment using `seek()` to jump straight to the desired part of the file -- so your only O(n) operation (taking linear time based on number of lines) is that once-a-day indexing.

Comment: it's read only, and used maybe a couple times a month as the data gets republished and i update a mysql db with the new info.  the lines are heterogeneous (but in groups - imagine a db record from table A and its related records from tables B/C/D/E/F, with relationships inferred from the B/C/D/E/F records following the A record). these groups e.g. ABBCDEEEFF,ABCCCCD,AB etc are repeated throughout the file.  so i have to add some of A to each BCDEF row during segregation so the relationship isn't lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is too big to read in whole. The good news is that the contents of a process substitution is a shell script, so you can write:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ...
done < <(

    if   [[ $x && $y ]];  then  tail -n +"$x" "$filename" | head -n "$y"
    elif [[ $x ]];        then  tail -n +"$x" "$filename"
    elif [[ $y ]];        then  head -n "$y" "$filename"
    else                        cat "$filename"
    fi

)
```

One thing I don't like about process substitutions is that code **follows** the loop for which it is input. It would be nice if it appeared first. I think this will work, but is untested:

```
# set up file descriptor 3
exec 3< <(
    if   [[ $x && $y ]];  then  tail -n +"$x" "$filename" | head -n "$y"
    elif [[ $x ]];        then  tail -n +"$x" "$filename"
    elif [[ $y ]];        then  head -n "$y" "$filename"
    else                        cat "$filename"
    fi
)

# iterate over lines read from fd 3
while IFS= read -u3 -r line; do
    ...
done

# close fd 3
exec 3<&-
```

Comment: If you wrap the loop in a function, you *can* put the input first; `< <(...) my_loop_function`.

Comment: or I could put the *input* in a function and then `while read ... done < <(my_input_func)`

Answer (score 1):

I might handle all of these as part of the loop condition, with an explicitly maintained line counter.

```
start=10
end=30
i=0
while ((i <= end )) && IFS= read -r line; do
   (( i++ >= start )) || continue
   ...
done < "$filename"
```

However, if you might skip a significant number of lines at the beginning, it might be more efficient to use `sed`

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ...
done < <(sed -n "$start,$stop p" "$filename")
```

or `awk`:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   ...
done < <(awk -v start "$start" -v end "$end" 'NR >= start && NR <= end' "$filename")
```

This then raises the question of how much of the body of the `while` loop can be moved into `awk` itself.

Comment: Your `continue` prevents the `(( i += 1 ))` from being run. Might be safer to make it `(( i++ >= start ))` -- that way the increment always happens if the comparison does, without impacting it.

Comment: @erich, `tail | head` isn't *that* fast (if you're skipping large numbers of lines). If you want something that's *genuinely* fast, you need to make sure your content can be bisected -- ie. that it has the line numbers inside the contents, so code can seek to a chosen byte offset, read from there and figure out where it is. Which is to say, you need to actually build your content format with seek-time performance in mind, *or* build and maintain an index into it -- neither of which are easy -- to get amortized-constant-time seeks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i have no control over the file format, i just have to live with it. :/

Comment: The other question is where your line numbers come from. If it's code you write that tracks how many lines you've already processed, for instance -- change it to track how many *bytes* you already processed, since you can seek via byte offset (caveat: into a real file, but not a FIFO) instantly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right; the perils of rethinking my approach multiple times while writing the code.